# Which version of Fedora, RHEL, correspond to which version of CentOS?

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

Which version of Fedora, RHEL, correspond to which version of CentOS?

Answer (score 5):

Fedora does not correspond directly to RHEL or CentOS; RHEL is built from pieces of Fedora, but not the whole thing.

The latest RHEL and CentOS versions are directly comparable, except for prerelease versions. Older versions of RHEL have a "u" to indicate the update release where CentOS has a "." to indicate the minor version.

Also note that delays in having gotten CentOS 6 out mean that CentOS 6.0 is slightly ahead of RHEL 6.0, although the CentOS developers plan to have this straightened out with 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

There is no relation between fedora version and RHEL, Centos version. Fedora is a community project with a release in each 6 months. But RHEL and its clone Centos are enterprise-grade distributions with long release gap. CentOS is a clone of RHEL with branding/artwork etc removed from RHEL. Since the logo, artwork etc are the property of Redhat, it is not possible for a community distro to use that. CentOS removes the brading from RHEL and releases the Centos distro. Centos follows the same release cycle as RHEL but lags behind RHEL. RHEL 6 was released this year and CentOS will release version 6 in 2011.

Comment: It's impossible for RHEL 6 to have appeared 10 years after RHEL 5, since the entire support period for RHEL 5 is 10 years (recently up from 7), and it's still very much supported.

Comment: Wikipedia [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhel#Version_history) RHEL 5 as being released in 2007, so you're right that it can't be 10 years.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I ment 10 years support cycle. not release cycle.